Can a community user create an Expense in Salesforce?
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5
Is the list provided here is exhaustive ?
Will it work for this
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_expense.htm

It's not exhaustive, here's another list. Talk to your Salesforce account manager, they'll sort you out.

Also open a support case and ask for clarification.
